# Two-Dimensional array, cannot succesfully fill with data.

Tags: c++

I am using this class below

```
template<typename T>
class array_2d 
{
public:
    std::size_t data;
    std::size_t col_max;
    std::size_t row_max;
    std::vector<T> a;

    array_2d(std::size_t col, std::size_t row) : data(col*row), col_max(col), row_max(row), a(data)
    {}

    T& operator()(std::size_t col, std::size_t row) 
    {
        assert(col_max > col && row_max > row);
        return a[col_max*col + row];
    }
};
```

And initializing it as so

```
    array_2d<CString> tableData(5, 2);
    for(int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
        for(int c = 0; c < 2; c++)
            tableData(r, c) = "Test";
```

And keep coming back that I am exceeding the bounds of a vector. I have been trying for hours to get a successful 2-dimensional CString array.

Comment: You've confused yourself into mixing up `row`, `col`, `r` and `c`. Read again carefully.

Comment: Most 2-d array APIs that I know want the row number first, then the column number -- you might want your template class to follow that convention (your own code seems to expect it).

Comment: I agree with @Kerrek, you are probably better off using terms like "width", "height", "x" and "y". it is much more clear (at least to me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say `tableData(c, r) = "Test";`.

Answer (score 1):

Erm.. your arguments/parameter order are mixed up...

Answer (score 1):

`tableData(r, c) = "Test";`

vs

`T& operator()(std::size_t col, std::size_t row)`

Surely that can't work.